# Git Pages: How to link a script file (or any other files) from a branch into the main branch

Tags: github, github-pages, git-branch

I am new to github & git pages!
I have an assets branch to store files like css, scrpts, photos, etc.
To keep everything organized and free of "clutter" from my main branch, which is the one I am using to "serve" the pages.

How can I link a script file into my html from the main branch? So far the links I get from the assets branch are to the repo not for good for html.

For example, the file BackgroundModule.js from my assets branch is located here:
`scripts/BackgroundModule.js`

And this is the link to my main branch: `https://omarjuvera.github.io/Portfolios/`

**If possible**, I would like the link to be structured like this: `https://omarjuvera.github.io/Portfolios/assets/scripts/BackgroundModule.js` while keeping each branch intact

Answer (score 1):

You need to link to the raw file content. Github provides the actual file content under this domain https://raw.githubusercontent.com

I have checked your github profile and prepared this link to the BackgroundModule.js as an example.

Example raw file content link:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/omarjuvera/Portfolios/assets/scripts/BackgroundModule.js

Sample link to the script in your html document:

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/omarjuvera/Portfolios/assets/scripts/BackgroundModule.js"></script>
```

Comment: For some reason, the script does not work when I use external files with raw `<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/omarjuvera/Portfolios/assets/scripts/BackgroundModule.js"></script>` I am using https://omarjuvera.github.io/Portfolios/Cybersecurity/test-background.html and https://omarjuvera.github.io/Portfolios/Cybersecurity/test-background-links.html to test. What could it be?